# MongoDB - Retrieve only the matching subdocument AND the root document

Tags: mongodb

Edit:
Problem solved, see below.

I have the following document:

```
db.clients.insert({
    _id: ObjectId("524d720d8d3ea014a52e95bb"),
    company: "Example",
    logins: [
        {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "username": "test",
            "password": "eF9wnBEys0OzL5vmR/OHGCaekHiw/Miy+XvbDdayxeo=",
            "email": "a@a.com",
            "last": null,
            "roles": ["CONFIG"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Guest",
            "username": "guest",
            "password": "K/gYODb7XPo0erySvL276DyPi4+stPPK4jM3pJ8aaVg=",
            "email": "a@a.com",
            "last": null,
            "roles": []
        }
    ]
});
```

And now, I want to authenticate my clients, using this document. But, I don't want to retrieve every sub logins, I want only the one which match.

That's why I'm using an aggregate:

```
db.clients.aggregate(
    {
        "$project": {
            "login": "$logins",
            "_id": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$login"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$login.username",
            "login": {
                "$first": "$login"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "login.username": "test",
            "login.password": "eF9wnBEys0OzL5vmR/OHGCaekHiw/Miy+XvbDdayxeo=",
        }
    }
);
```

Which works fine, giving me:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "test",
                        "login" : {
                                "name" : "John Smith",
                                "username" : "test",
                                "password" : "eF9wnBEys0OzL5vmR/OHGCaekHiw/Miy+XvbDdayxeo=",
                                "email" : "a@a.com",
                                "last" : null,
                                "roles" : [
                                        "CONFIG"
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

But now, the tricky part is that I would like to retrieve also the root document fields. Such as `_id` and `company` for example.

But no matter what I try, I can't manage to do it. Do you have a solution? :)

---

Edit:

Ok, in fact it wasn't that hard. I'm sorry!

```
db.clients.aggregate(
    {
        "$project": {
            "login": "$logins",
            "_id": "$_id",
            "company": "$company"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$login"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$login.username",
            "login": {
                "$first": "$login"
            },
            "clientId": {
                "$first": "$_id"
            },
            "company": {
                "$first": "$company"
            },
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "login.username": "test",
            "login.password": "eF9wnBEys0OzL5vmR/OHGCaekHiw/Miy+XvbDdayxeo=",
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: So post an answer to your own question, that's ok.

Comment: I'm new on stackoverflow, so I'm low in reputation. I can't answer my own question before 8 hours :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with a `find` and the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/#proj._S_) positional projection operator as well:

```js
db.clients.find({
        "logins.username": "test",
        "logins.password": "eF9wnBEys0OzL5vmR/OHGCaekHiw/Miy+XvbDdayxeo=",
    }, {
        "logins.$": 1,
        "company": 1
    })
```

The `$` in the projection contains the index of the `logins` array element that was matched in the query.

Output:

```js
{
  "_id": ObjectId("524d720d8d3ea014a52e95bb"),
  "company": "Example",
  "logins": [
    {
      "name": "John Smith",
      "username": "test",
      "password": "eF9wnBEys0OzL5vmR/OHGCaekHiw/Miy+XvbDdayxeo=",
      "email": "a@a.com",
      "last": null,
      "roles": [
        "CONFIG"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to return only selected fields in the sub document?  ie only `logins` > `name` ?  I tried `logins.$.name` but it returns the whole sub document.

Comment: @user1063287 I would have expected that to work. Best to post a new question with the details.

Answer (score 2):

A bit shorter variant:

```
db.clients.aggregate(
  {$match:{"logins.username":"test"}},
  {$unwind:"$logins"},
  {$match:{"logins.username":"test","logins.password":"eF9wnBEys0OzL5vmR/OHGCaekHiw/Miy+XvbDdayxeo="}}
)
```

Output is:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("524d720d8d3ea014a52e95bb"),
                        "company" : "Example",
                        "logins" : {
                                "name" : "John Smith",
                                "username" : "test",
                                "password" : "eF9wnBEys0OzL5vmR/OHGCaekHiw/Miy+XvbDdayxeo=",
                                "email" : "a@a.com",
                                "last" : null,
                                "roles" : [
                                        "CONFIG"
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: i think you need to `unwind` first before `{$match:{"logins.username":"test"}}`.

Comment: No you don't need to unwind.

Comment: because, one level of array check by this ?

Comment: All elements of array will be checked.